# RecyclerView BackgroundColor

Tags: android, colors, android-recyclerview

I used a `RecyclerView` to display some text data. I got the logic in it to select different cards.

I would like to change the appearance of the selected cards.

```
public void toggleSelection(int pos)
    {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recView.findViewHolderForPosition(pos);
        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }
```

If I use my code like this it works. My onClick event triggers this code and my card background color changes to green.

So here is my problem: scrolling down shows other cards in the same relative position (but further down in the list) with the same background color even if they are not selected; selecting the first card and scrolling down to where the eighth card is the top visible card shows the eighth card highlighted.

Comment: I really am not sure how to rephrase your last line. Can you say it another way?

Comment: lets say i got 32 items in my recyclerview - now i click on item with index 0 - it gets selected and changes the background color - but item with index 8 (which is literally out of screen the first item) gets the same background color if i scroll down.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the colors explicitly in `onBindViewHolder()` method. 
A recycler view as the name suggests recycles views, so 0th item is recycled as the 8th item in your case. They use the same view holder created using the `onCreateViewHolder()` method.And each time any one of them comes into view the `onBindViewHolder()` method is called.
I suggest you create an additional boolean field in your data model, telling you whether you've highlighted the view or not. You should toggle it in `toggleSelection()`.
Then in the `onBindViewHolder()` you check the value of this field and set your color accordingly.