# Put different background colors for each item in a ViewHolder

Tags: android, gridview, background, android-viewholder

I have created a GridView using a ViewHolder Adapter to include in each item an image and some text.
The code is correctly working and the display is smooth, but now I want to add a different background colors to each item. I have checked severals posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793853/android-viewholder-background-color) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836840/recyclerview-backgroundcolor), but I cannot manage to make it work.

The GridViewAdapter is created in `Main Activity`:

```
private List<GridViewItem> mItems;    // GridView items list
private GridViewAdapter mAdapter;    // GridView adapter
```

And is used in `onCreate` as follows:

```
mItems = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();
Resources resources = getResources();

mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.truck_package), getString(R.string.drop_package)));
mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.man_package), getString(R.string.pick_package)));
mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.register), getString(R.string.register)));
mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, mItems);
// initialize the GridView
final GridView gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My GridViewAdapter works as follows:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<GridViewItem> mItems;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<GridViewItem> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        GridViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * The view holder design pattern prevents using findViewById()
     * repeatedly in the getView() method of the adapter.
     *
     * @see ://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
    }
}
```

Finally, each item of the GridView is defined as follows:

```
public class GridViewItem {
    public final Drawable icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;        // the text for the GridView item title


    public GridViewItem(Drawable icon, String title) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;

    }
}
```

My guess is that I should add a "color" variable in the `GridViewItem`. Then use it with `viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color)` in `GridViewAdapter` per both the text and the image. Do you think is the right approach? If so, how would you do it?

Finally, and I am not totally sure if this is the most optimal way to use the gridView, so I would appreciate to know if there is a better way to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me. I believe this is the right way.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Which variable is the right one to put in each item? `Color` or `ColorDrawable`. and after, how do I call this color with `viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color)`?

Comment: `Color` should be simple and sufficient if you just want to give those items a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parent layout id of `R.layout.gridview_item` file. assume you have line layout is parent layout in that file then use below way.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.line_list_item = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.line_list_item);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        GridViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
                viewHolder.line_main.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            } else {
                viewHolder.line_main.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
            }

        return convertView;
    }
```